# Visual Studio 2012 HTML Editor - 'Go To Definition'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, html-editor

Is there an easy way to "Go To Definition" of an ASP.Net Control event while using the Visual Studio HTML Editor?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Create New Employer" ID="btnCreateNewEmployer" OnClick="btnCreateNewEmployer_Click" />
```

I want to access btnCreateNewEmployer_Click method in the code behind without having to scroll through it or doing a ctrl-F to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think is by having the focus on the button and pressing Keyboard's "F4" button or clicking on the "Properties" menu and then go to events tab which has this defintion. Otherwise, you can always go to the Design View and double click on the button itself.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Double Clicking only brings up the default event, which is only useful sometimes. Plus I try to avoid Design View as much as possible.

Comment: When I place the focus in the HTML editor, the event tab only shows up sometimes in the property window, think it is a VS 11 bug. Very annoying.

Comment: Just realized, I don't get the Event tab for the focused control when it is nested inside of a Formview. Again, very annoying as I use Formviews all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension for VS 2012 it’s available for free:

It enables you to `Make ctrl+click perform a "Go To Definition" on the identifier under the cursor.`

[Go To Definition](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have this extension. It only works for the code behind file, not in the HTML Editor.